# Mysql import table issue

Tags: html, mysql

folks. I've got a problem with this mysql code, can you fix it please?

```
CREATE TABLE `websites` (
   `id` varchar(200),
   `totalrate` int(11) default '0',
   `nrrates` int(9) default '1',
   `Web-site_name` varchar(200) not null,
   `Author` varchar(200) not null,
   `URL` varchar(200) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `websites` (`id`, `totalrate`, `nrrates`, `Web-site_name`, `Author`, `URL`) VALUES
('id_0', '0', '1', 'Avengers', 'Zachar Kapustin', '/websites/Av/index.html'),
('id_1', '0', '1', 'Matvey Productions', 'Matvey Shmakov', '/websites/matvey/website.html'),
('id_2', '0', '1', '101Patryks', 'Patryk Sobczak', '/websites/PatrykS/Gamelay.htm'),
('id_3', '0', '1', 'Side-Splitting Studios', 'Jakub Priban, Lena Szegda', '/websites/Jakub/home.htm'),
('id_4', '0', '1', 'JIGSAW TheMovie', 'Jolana Samii', '/websites/Jolana/jigsawthemovie.htm'),
('id_5', '0', '1', 'Spurl company ', 'Jan Zverinsky', '/websites/janZ/homepage.htm'),
('id_6', '0', '1', 'Sabing Destiny', 'Amy L.', '/websites/AmyL/SavingDestiny.htm'),
```

Comment: Ok - let's play 'guess the problem'...

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the ending comma `,` with a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 1):

Pleas remove the comma `,` at the end

[**See working fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e6d1/1)